# how to define a value for a scrollpane to appear from?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, scrollpane

Im working on a ux for a game, the construction of the ux in short is: AnchorPane->ScrollPane->AnchorPane->BorderPane, etc.
The problem im currently having is that the horizental scroller appears only when the window is really small, which when resizing the window pushes some components over others. 
Therefore i wanted to define a value on which the horizental scroller will appear and work. altought the policy of the vbar and hbar are marked as needed - the hbar doesnt show up when needed. 
I know it sounds easy, but ive tried and looked for a solution but without luck.

is there any way to do it?

P.s, ive added some pictures that describes the above, as you can see the vertical scroller works as needed, the horizental one doesnt.

[hbar doesnt work as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVru4.png)

thanks in advance,
tom.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This can only be done by controling the size of the content which you seem to have already tried. There's probably something wrong with this code though. It's not possible to help you with this issue though, unless you provide some code...